# Why is my UPS causing my monitor to make a high pitched humming noise

Tags: power-supply, power, ups

I recently purchased a UPS for a new server build for my home. Since the server sits next to my desk, I figured I'd plug my Macbook and monitor into the UPS as well. That way if the power goes out, I can finish what I was working on without my Mac going to sleep.

However, there's a high pitched noise coming from my Thunderbolt display when connected to the UPS. I tried another monitor as well (an old Dell), and that one also has the same type of humming noise. Once I switch the displays to another outlet (either direct, or to a surge protector, the humming stops on both monitors. If the monitors are connected to the UPS but turned off, there is no humming.

Why would this be happening? My UPS is a CyberPower CP1500PFCLCD, which is a sinewave UPS. From my understanding, the sinewave feature of the UPS should actually be preventing something like this from happening. I'm guessing there is some sort of ground loop issue or power issue from the UPS that's causing the power supplies in my monitors to behave oddly.

It's an easy fix switching my monitors to another outlet/surge protector, but I'm curious why my UPS would cause this issue. I have a bunch of other electronics connected to the UPS (such as my 2 PSU's from my server, studio monitors, and one or two other devices). All of them function correctly and there's no odd noises coming form them or the UPS. But once I connect either of my monitors and turn them on, the high pitched humming noise begins. The UPS usually sits at 20% load, and all the health reports say it's working well.

Comment: What are the input and output line voltages as reported on the front panel?  What happens if nothing is connected to the UPS but the monitor?

Comment: Both input and output voltages are at 121v. If only the monitor is connected, the monitor still makes a humming/whining noise.

Comment: When you disconnect the UPS from the mains outlet does the monitor still emit the noise?

Answer (score -1):

First off whats the ups make/model.
If it is a line interrupt model such as most battery backups there should be no harmonics, whereas if it is in avr mode or is an online ups not a line interrupt or avr mode ups you may have a bigger problem with your household power.

Some things to check:

1. Make sure your ground wire outside your house is secure, should be attached to a copper ground rod under your main meter box. The wire should be tight to the rod.
2. Make sure your outlet is grounded, you would be surprised how often this gets unnoticed. Check for voltage between your ground and neutral, if there is any call an electrician.
3. If the surge is between the battery backup and the wall your ok, if the surge comes off of your battery backup replace with a power tap. This may seem unusual but some ups models can have harmonic feedback from a surge protector. Please don't get me started about floating neutrals and missing grounds with some cheaper ups models. Also how old is the home, I ask this as the age may indicate the method of wiring used, older houses may not have a ground wire running to the outlet.

Edit:
The buzzing noise you are hearing are due to several factors. Since you mentioned it only occurs when plugged directly into a ups indicates the ups isn't in its normal state, it may be in a power correction state aka avr or just an online ups (converts ac power to dc then back to ac) and the inverter is doing something wrong such as outputting a square wave or the monitor can't handle the modified sine wave (really cheap vs cheaper). Most online ups's are quite expensive usually more than pure sinewave ups's and are usually less efficient ~60-80%.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).