# PSU Power Supply makes a high pitch sound when pc is off

Tags: power-supply, power

Let me be clear about a few things. The power plug is plugged into the PSU (obviously) but the power switch is turned ON. If I turn off the switch with the plug is still plugged in, the noise or sound eventually goes away after 15-20 seconds (assuming after the power flow into the power supply has gone away completely.)

I've already seen [this](https://superuser.com/questions/625124/why-is-my-ups-causing-my-monitor-to-make-a-high-pitched-humming-noise). Which didn't help me much.

1. Why does this occur?
2. How can I stop the noise period?
3. Does this mean the power supply is faulty?

Aside form the high pitch when the computer is off, the psu works just fine. Thanks.

Edit: The PSU is brand new, opened out of the box 24 hours ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you have leaky capacitors in your PSU, a sign it's beginning to fail.

Capacitors and alike do fail, sometimes just because of age, sometimes because of shoddy manufacturing.  IME the PSU is the most-often replaced part in a PC.

The way to make it stop squealing is to replace the PSU.

If the PSU is brand new, then you may just want to hold off replacing it for a couple weeks, to give it a chance to correct itself under load ('burn off [the flux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux_(metallurgy))' as we used to say).  I've RARELY seen this help though.  If it's still doing it after a couple weeks, I'd take it back and get a replacement.